# .NET 6 large file handling with token expiration

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have a concern regarding large file handling in .NET 6. I send a file (100MB) via an Android phone to .NET 6 web api endpoint and that request endup with `StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized`. My concern is since a large file is received by the web api will that get disposed properly?

I have a retry written for that large file's failure on the Android, and I have observed a memory hike on the server that does not go down and eventually server hangs and crashes.

I'm looking for a solution on either how to properly dispose of the received document or some insight on how .NET 6 handles this kind of a scenario when developers do not need to worry.

I know I should be handling a 401 error. My concern is not just for the 401 error but also for other errors as well. I just want to know what happens internally.

Android code for sending a file:

```
private void runAnnotationBackup(SharedPreferences cooperatePrefs){
try {

new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

List<Version> versions = versionViewModel.getBackupNeededAnnotationsData();
if(versions!=null && !isAnnotationUploadRunning){
if(versions.size()==0) return null;
String pdfDirPath = Constants.getUserOriginalAnnotationDirectory(UserInitActivity.this, user);
File annotationsFolder = new File(pdfDirPath);
if(!annotationsFolder.isDirectory()) return null;
isAnnotationUploadRunning = true;
FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("*.xfdf");
File[] files = annotationsFolder.listFiles(fileFilter);
for (Version ver : versions) {
for (File file : files) {
String fileName = file.getName();
String[] fileData = fileName.split("_");
String filePaperId = fileData[0];
String versionId = fileData[2].substring(0, fileData[2].length() - 5);
if(ver.getPaperId() == Integer.parseInt(filePaperId) && ver.getIsAnnotBackupNeeded() == 1){
File reqfile = new File(file.getPath());
MultipartBody.Part[] fileParts = new MultipartBody.Part[1];

RequestBody fileBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"), reqfile);
fileParts[0] = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("files", reqfile.getName(), fileBody);
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

int randomInt = random.nextInt(1000000000);
SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesV4User = UserInitActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(
SharedPrefDetails.getSharedPreferencesV4User(UserInitActivity.this, "222"), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String loginResponseAccessToken = sharedPreferencesV4User.getString("LoginResponseAccessToken", null);

AnnotationShareRequest annotationShareRequest = new AnnotationShareRequest();
annotationShareRequest.setPaperVersionId(Integer.parseInt(versionId));
annotationShareRequest.setUniqueIdDevice(randomInt);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String annotationPart = gson.toJson(annotationShareRequest);
RequestBody annotationData = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), annotationPart);
Call<Void> annotationBackupRequest = bpmainapi.uploadAnnotationsForPaparV4(
"Bearer " + loginResponseAccessToken,
filePaperId,
filePaperId,
"5",
annotationData,
fileParts
);

annotationBackupRequest.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {
if (response.code()==200) {
Version paperVersion = new Version();
paperVersion.setVersionId(Integer.parseInt(versionId));
paperVersion.setPaperId(Integer.parseInt(filePaperId));
paperVersion.setAnnotBackupStatus(0);
paperVersion.setIsAnnotBackupNeeded(BoardPACEnumsReference.AnnotBackup.NoNeed);
paperVersion.setCurrentPage(0);
paperVersion.setCreatedDate(new Date());
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
versionViewModel.updateAnnotationBackupNeededForPaper(paperVersion);
isAnnotationUploadRunning = false;
cooperatePrefs.edit().putString(SharedPreferencesCooperate.lastAnnotationBackupDate, SettingsCache.getInstance().getServerTime()).apply();
return null;
}
}.execute();
} else {
isAnnotationUploadRunning = false;
}
}
@Override
public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
isAnnotationUploadRunning = false;
}
});
}else{
isAnnotationUploadRunning = false;
}

}
}
}
return null;
}
}.execute();
}catch (Exception e){
}
```

.NET 6 web API code for receiving the file:

```
[HttpPost("{id}/backup-annotations")]
    [RefIdValidator("id")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> BackupAnnotationsAsync(int id, [ModelBinder(typeof(JsonWithFilesFormDataModelBinder), Name = "annotation")][Required] AnnotationModel model, IFormFileCollection files)
    {
        if (files.Count == 0) return Problem(statusCode: 400, title: "No annotations found to backup");
        if (files.Count > 1) return Problem(statusCode: 400, title: "Only annotations can be backed up, not paper and annotations");

        model.PaperId = id;
        model.CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow; //Do not remove, used for encryption
        await _annotationService.BackupAnnotationsAsync(model, files);

        return Ok();
    }
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your question is to vague to be answerable.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama Im asking does .NET framework itself take care the disposal of the received file or do we have to do anything from the code. :)

Comment: Can you provide details of how you're sending/receiving the files?

Comment: Putting code inside a "Using" block will ensure that the object gets disposed after exiting the block.  The Garbage Collection (GC) only runs when necessary so it may not get disposed immediately.

Comment: @jdweng Correct. Here the issue is sometimes the http call won't even reach to our api call and it returns early due to issues like token expiration. When that happens does the framework dispose the received file?

Comment: GC is a scheduled event that only runs when memory usage gets large.  GC checks the links to object and only removes an object when the number links to the object are zero.  Class objects are passed BYREF (a link) so sometimes the number of links do not go to zero which causes memory leaks. When you exit a Using block in most cases the number of links drop to zero, but sometimes you create another link inside the using block and the number of links are not zero. When you send a request with an expired token the connection is completed and you get a response. The connection should get disposed.